# Can't correctly display GeoJSON on D3

Tags: geojson, wgs84, d3

I'm trying to display some GeoJSON files with D3. The code is pretty simple:

```
import europe_data from "./data/europe.json";
import areas_data from "./data/LV.json";

/******************************************/

const [states, setStates] = useState(europe_data);
const [areas, setAreas] = useState(areas_data);

/******************************************/

const projection = geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], states);
const pathGenerator = geoPath().projection(projection);

// render each state
svg
  .selectAll(".state")
  .data(states.features)
  .join("path")
  .attr("class", "state")
  .attr("d", (feature) => pathGenerator(feature));

// render LV areas
svg
  .selectAll(".area")
  .data(areas.features)
  .join("path")
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", (feature) => pathGenerator(feature));
```

However, I can't correctly display LV.

[image: This is the rendering of Europe]

This is the rendering of Europe.

[image: This should be the rendering of some areas in Latvia, filled in purple]

This should be the rendering of some areas in Latvia, filled in purple.

I need to work with files from various sources and format, so I'm converting all of them with [mapshaper](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper) in GeoJSON file formatted in WGS84.

[These](https://gist.github.com/epilurzu/2de3cab3c25ca6007f97feaa32ca1328) are the GeoJSON files I'm using.

Why can't I display LV.json?

EDIT:

The GeoJSON files both contain the keys type, geometry, and properties, even if in a different order. It doesn't affect the output.

Comment: there are missing parameters see https://medium.com/@amy.degenaro/introduction-to-digital-cartography-geojson-and-d3-js-c27f066aa84

Comment: They both contain the keys type, geometry, and properties, even if in a different order. It doesn't affect the output.